# Communication between PHP and Perl CGI scripts

Tags: php, web-services, perl, cgi

I have two scripts that carry out different tasks on a server. One is written in Perl (.cgi) the other in PHP.

I am trying to send out a request from the perl CGI script by doing something like this:

```
$ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;
$ua->agent("$0/0.1 " . $ua->agent);
$ua->timeout(30);

$queryStr = (xxxMaskedxxx);
$request = HTTP::Request->new('GET', $queryStr);
$response = $ua->request($request);
if ($response->is_success)
{
        $search = strpos($res->content, "not");
        if($search==true)
        { return -1; }
}
```

I tried two ways to send back the result from PHP:

This:

```
HttpResponse::setCache(true);
HttpResponse::setContentType('text/html');
if (!$result)
        HttpResponse::setData("<html>Message not delivered</html>");
else
        HttpResponse::setData("<html>Message successfully delivered</html>");
HttpResponse::send();
```

And this:

```
echo "Content-type: text/html\n\n";
if (!$result)
      echo 'Message not delivered' . PHP_EOL;
else
      echo 'Message successfully delivered' . PHP_EOL;
```

But `$response->is_success` returns false for both case? When I try to print the response out, I am getting this:

```
response is HTTP::Response=HASH(0x97a8b34)
```

What have I done wrong?

Also the two scripts are sitting side by side. Are there any better ways to communicate between them?

Comment: `(xxxMaskedxxx);` should probably be `"xxxMaskedxxx";` You could execute php script from perl, if there is `php cli` version installed.

Comment: @mpapec do you have a sample that I can follow? I am still not clear on how to capture the return from the PHP script using php cli.

Comment: take a look at sample below. php in `cli` mode takes command line arguments which are stored in `$argv`

Answer (score 1):

Perl calling `cli.php` script with command line arguments,

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

my $content = `/usr/bin/php cli.php xxxMaskedxxx`;

print $content;
```

`cli.php` echoing back received argument

```
<?php

// output first argument from command line
print $argv[1];
```

Answer (score 1):

> But $response->is_success returns false for both case?

In both cases, you are outputting the default [HTTP status](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html), which is "200 OK". You need to [output a status code](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-response-code.php) that indicates failure for `is_success` to fail.

> When I try to print the response out, I am getting this

That's an [`HTTP::Response` object](https://metacpan.org/module/HTTP%3a%3aResponse). You need to examine `$response->decoded_content` if you want to get the text out of it.